# Copying data from multiple worksheets from other workbook to current worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to copy data from multiple worksheets in another workbook to the current worksheet and encountered

> Run-time error 1004
>     "Copy method of Range class failed"

The error occurred at:

```
Rows(j).Copy _
    (thisws.Range("A300000").End(xlUp).Offset(1,0)
```

Appreciate the help as I am a newbie to Excel VBA.

```
Sub copyEPOSaging()
    Dim strUserFile As String        
    Dim thiswb As Workbook        
    Dim wb As Workbook        
    Dim thisws As Worksheet        
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set thiswb = ThisWorkbook        
    Set thisws = thiswb.Sheets("ePOS")

    'Opening File dialog box        
    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker).Show

    'assign variable to identify selected file using dialog box        
    strUserFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker).SelectedItems(1)

    'open the selected file        
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strUserFile)                 

    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Integer

    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count - 1        
        With wb.Sheets(i)        
            lastRow = Range("A200000").End(xlUp).Row        
            For j = 3 To lastRow
                Rows(j).Copy _
                    (thisws.Range("A300000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0))
            Next j
        End With
    Next i

    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you run the sub step by step with F8 ? maybe you want paste something in row zero

Comment: When you are inside `With wb.Sheets(i) ... End With` you should be using `.Range` and `.Rows`. Note the prefix `.`

Comment: Why aren't you copying all of the rows at once? Copying 1 row at a tie in a loop seems a waste of tie.